# extracting a string from between to strings in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-preprocessing

im trying to extract a value from my data frame
i have a column ['Desc'] it contains sentences in the folowing format

> _000it_ZZZ$$$-

> _0780it_ZBZT$$$-

> _011it_BB$$$-

> _000it_CCCC$$$-

I want to extract the string between 'it_' and '$$$'

I have tried this code but does not seem to work

```
# initializing substrings
sub1 = "it_"
sub2 = "$$$"
 
# getting index of substrings
idx1 = df['DESC'].find(sub1)
idx2 = df['DESC'].find(sub2)
 
# length of substring 1 is added to
# get string from next character
df['results'] = df['DESC'][idx1 + len(sub1) + 1: idx2]
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: You want "str.find" instead of "find" and "str.slice" for the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the desired output in your new column.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DESC' : ["_000it_ZZZ$$$-", "_0780it_ZBZT$$$-", "_011it_BB$$$-", "_000it_CCCC$$$-", "_000it_123$$$-"]
})

pat = r"(?<=it_)(.+)(?=[\$]{3}-)"
df['results'] = df['DESC'].str.extract(pat)
print(df)
```

```
               DESC results
0    _000it_ZZZ$$$-     ZZZ
1  _0780it_ZBZT$$$-    ZBZT
2     _011it_BB$$$-      BB
3   _000it_CCCC$$$-    CCCC
4    _000it_123$$$-     123
```

You can see the regex pattern on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c1UL61/1) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a regex pattern. It matches your cases you listed here, but I can't guarantee that it will generalize to all possible patterns.

```py
import re

string = "_000it_ZZZ$$$-"
p = re.compile(r"(?<=it_)(.*)(?<!\W)")
m = p.findall(string)
print(m) # ['_ZZZ']
```

The pattern looks for `it` in the string and then stops untill it meets a non-word character.

Comment: can I edit this so it stops after occurrence of word character ? if the $$$ were SSS for example and ZZZ were 123 for instance

Comment: Borrowing from the answer below, but using the pattern `(?<=it)(.*)(?=[\$]{3}-$)` seems to do the trick.

Comment: The pattern I originally used works for any letter (case insensitive) and digits. This means that if the inner string could have `_, -, .` it would stop prematurely. The new pattern only stops at the occurence of _exactly_ 3 $ signs

Comment: your help has been incredible thanks a lot. but if you could help me with one more thing. I tried this code with another format that is :  _000it_123$$$- However im getting NaN . do you know how can i deal with this please?

Comment: i wanted to extract 123

Comment: Must something wrong in your code, when running this line in Regex101 it fetches the correct substring. Check it our here https://regex101.com/r/PIbioG/1

Comment: @Rabinzel
 I'm still getting NaN :(

Comment: @leena maybe you have trailing whitespaces in that string. My pattern checks for exactly 3 `$` signs, followed by a `-`, followed by `$` which asserts end of line/string. Try to replace my pattern `pat` with: `r"(?<=it_)(.+)(?=[\$]{3}-)"`

Comment: yessssssssss it worked Thank you